# Robospice upload file with SpringAndroidSpiceRequest

Tags: android, spring, robospice

I am working with robospice. Now I want to upload file. 
I used SpringAndroidSpiceService and write my own request like this :

```
public class UploadFileRequest extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<String>{
private static final String TAG = "UploadFileRequest";
private UploadRequestModel requestModel;
private String link;
public UploadFileRequest(UploadRequestModel model, String link) {
    super(String.class);
    requestModel = model;
    this.link = link;
}

@Override
public String loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {    

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    parts.add("file1", new FileSystemResource(requestModel.getFile1()));
    parts.add("file2", new FileSystemResource(requestModel.getFile1()));

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = 
            new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parts, headers);

    return getRestTemplate().postForObject(link, request, String.class);

}

}
```

I can send the files now. But I faced a problem.
After the files have sent. My files on disk are almost deleted. It's size is zero.
Do you know why ? and how can I resolve it ?
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: In the above code, you reference an object of type 'UploadRequestModel'.  I can't find any documentation on this object - can you give me some insight?

Comment: ah. UploadRequestModel is just a POJO class. Which I used to contain the files path.

Comment: Thanks, I figured out my problem - had to do with the message converters not being found.  Along the lines of  restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter()); , though according to the docs this isn't necessary, for it was.

Answer (score 1):

I am on of the authors of RS. The problem you face is not related to RS directly but to Spring Android. I suggest you write to their forum to get an answer. Sorry, but we can't tell you more.

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

```
        this.message.setApi_key(ConfigurationBean.getTab_id());
        this.message.setApi_password(ConfigurationBean.getTab_assword());
        this.message.setNursery_id(ConfigurationBean.getNursery_id());          
        url=ConfigurationBean.getNursery_url()+"/api/v1/installation.php";

        try {
            list=service.getConfiguration(admin, pass);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("request", ""+e.getMessage());
        }


        // Add the Jackson and String message converters
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        // Make the HTTP POST request, marshaling the request to JSON, and the response to a String
        String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, message, String.class);

        return response;
```

this is my code,
before i was getting the same problem ,not its working fine u can try this message `enter code here`converter which will help